# Snowflake streams not working as expected

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying use [Snowflake streams](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/streams-intro), but it doesn't work as expected.
Here are the steps I am taking to test it:

1. Creating a table `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE my_table (id INTEGER, name STRING);`
2. Creating a stream `CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM my_stream ON TABLE my_table;`
3. Insert one row `INSERT INTO my_table (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Alice');`
4. Checking the stream `SELECT * FROM my_stream;` And getting the expected result
   `Row=1, ID=1 , NAME=Alice, METADATA$ACTION=INSERT, METADATA$ISUPDATE=FALSE`
5. **ISSUE 1**: Now I am checking the stream again `SELECT * FROM my_stream;`, I expected to see empty result because the stream was already checked, and no further changes were made. However I am getting the exact same result `Row=1, ID=1 , NAME=Alice, METADATA$ACTION=INSERT, METADATA$ISUPDATE=FALSE`
6. Now I am testing it with *UPDATE* `UPDATE my_table SET id = 100 WHERE id = 1;`
7. **ISSUE 2**: Now checking the stream `SELECT * FROM my_stream;` I do see in the stream the updated ID, but I also expected `METADATA$ISUPDATE` to be TRUE, but it is still returned as FALSE.
   `Row=1, ID=100 , NAME=Alice, METADATA$ACTION=INSERT, METADATA$ISUPDATE=FALSE`

Anything I am doing wrong, or those are issues with Snowflake streams?

Comment: Selecting from a stream doesn’t affect the contents of a stream. The “window” against a stream only moves when you run a DML statement against the stream. There atpre good examples here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/streams-examples

Comment: STREAM needs to be consumed.For eg

CREATE OR REPLACE TARGET_TABLE Select id, name from STREAM

Stream offset pointer is tied to table transaction.
Create a table and stream on top of this table. When data is inserted, it is tied to unique transaction ID(T1 )here in case.
Running Select * from stream, advances upto trans T1.It means stream has data until T1 from when it was created. This is just a read and not consumption.

Once stream is consumed, stream will empty and offset moves to T1. It means stream has consumed data upto T1.